# String elements in array with whitespaces in them being splitted?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to use the next array's elements to replace some strings in a file:

```
declare -a replacements=($name, $description, $date, $keywords)
```

By using the search terms in this array:

```
declare -a searchs=("a.name", "a.description", "a.date", "a.keywords")
```

The problem is that some variables (`description`, for example) have whitespaces in them:

```
declare description = "My name is Jonah"
```

Which casuses a weird behaviour on the next piece of code:

```
for ((i = 0; i < ${#searchs[@]}; i++))
do
    sed -i -e "s/${searchs[$i]}/${replacements[$i]}/g" "./${directory}/data.txt"
done
```

The for loops uses every word in the string as a replacement instead of the whole string.

Is there a way to fix this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to auto close.  The commas in your array declaration are invalid however you also need to quote the variables.  `declare -a replacements=("$name" "$description" "$date" "$keywords")`

Comment: You might also want to use an [associative array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters) for this.

Comment: Commas where an error of mine while writing the code in here. I didn't want to use the actual code. Either way, the quoting is indeed the solution. Thanks a lot!